# SQL server Integration Services Package Requirements

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis

I am in process of building SSIS packages and i am totally lost with the confusion associated with this.

1. should we need Visual studio to create the SSIS packages?
2. should the SQL server data tools be sufficient to create the
   packages?
3. Is Visual Studio free to be downloaded?
4. When we install SQL server data tools, Will that install Visual
   Studio as well?

Thanks
santhosha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server Data Tools includes Visual Studio with Business Intelligence plugin so you do not have to install Visual Studio additionally. For SQL Server 2012 Data Tools is included to installation disk (this will install Visual Studio 2010). 
For SQL Server 2014, there is no Data Tools with installation disk, you have to download and install it manually: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313.

Comment: So anybody who has SQL server can use SSDT without any additional cost. Am i right?

Comment: @santhosha Correct.